# Dockerfile multiple lined env variable

Tags: environment-variables, dockerfile

How can I define this variable? Please help

```
ENV NGINX_REPO \
                  cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo <<EOF
                  [nginx]
                  name=nginx repo
                  baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/\$basearch/
                  gpgcheck=0
                  enabled=1
                  EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to docker-compose you can use an `.env` file. 
Check out this link https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules

But maybe you should pass this as a configuration file to your docker container. There are multiple ways of doing it:

- If you are in a docker swarm then simply refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/config/
- If you are using docker-compose then use the .env file as explained before
- Use `--volume` option to pass the config file to your container

Hope this could help you